# How do I translate this aggregate code to .NET or c#?

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I am have a little bit of trouble converting this code to `.NET`. It is between the two `[` `]`

```
db.account.aggregate([   {     $group: {       _id : null,       total: {$sum: 1},       "Pricebook ID": {$addToSet: "$Pricebook ID"},     },   },{     $project: {       "Pricebook ID":  { $eq:  [ "$total", {$size: "$Pricebook ID"}  ] }     }   } ]);
```

Currently, this is my code in `.NET`. Anyone knows the last part?

```
Dim Aggregate = Collection.Aggregate.
                          Group(
                                New BsonDocument From
                                      {
                                            {"_id", BsonNull.Value},
                                            {"total", New BsonDocument From
                                                  {
                                                        {"$sum", 1}
                                                  }
                                            },
                                            {"Pricebook ID", New BsonDocument From
                                                  {
                                                        {"$addToSet", "$Pricebook ID"}
                                                  }
                                            }
                                      }
                          ).
                          Project(
                                New BsonDocument From
                                {
                                      {"Pricebook ID", New BsonDocument From
                                            {
                                                  {"Pricebook ID", New BsonDocument From
                                                        {
                                                              {"$eq", <code here>}
                                                        }
                                                  }
                                            }
                                      }
                                }
                          )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out myself all thanks to this: [MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863150/mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-c-sharp)

Answer:

```
Dim Aggregate = Collection.Aggregate.
                          Group(New BsonDocument From {
                                            {"_id", BsonNull.Value},
                                            {"total", New BsonDocument From {
                                                        {"$sum", 1}}},
                                            {"Pricebook ID", New BsonDocument From {
                                                        {"$addToSet", "$Pricebook ID"}}}}
                          ).
                          Project(
                                New BsonDocument From {
                                      {"Pricebook ID", New BsonDocument From {
                                                  {"$eq", New BsonArray From {
                                                              "$total", New BsonDocument From {
                                                                    {"$size", "$Pricebook ID"}}}}}}}
                         )
```